# Identical nested divs hover effect

Tags: css

I have the following: [**http://jsfiddle.net/2hDB9/**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hDB9/)

How can I make it so that:

- if you hover over `Line 1`, it shows the border for just `Line 1`
- if you hover over `Line 2`, it shows the border for just `Line 2`, not both

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        Line 1.
        <div class="box">
            Line 2.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
}

.box {
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.box:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: But you want that if you hover on `Line 1` outside of 2 that `Line 1` gets the color?

Comment: You can't do it only with css beacuse you're always over the parent div ... with css you can't refere to parents and set stop it if i'm on one children

Comment: A good way of doing this is with jquery. First you have to import the jquery library, and then you can use the `hover` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need two different CSS classes for them. Since you have both Div's use the same `class="box"`, then the `.box:hover` command would be triggered on both div's.

For the css, you can set it so that only the inner `.box` class gets the hover command:

> `.box .box:hover {
>       border-color: red; }`

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2hDB9/2/

Comment: I think my question was unclear. I've edited the original post to make it easier to understand what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If all classes ***must*** be the same (as your title implies), then this isn't ***completely*** possible in ***pure* CSS**.

All the current answers only address **part** of the answer.. but if you insist, here is a jQuery solution - all elements have the same class, though I suggest you rename them, and avoid jQuery altogether.

Nonetheless, here is a solution, which **doesn't** require the class names to be changed:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/FjnA6/) - works for all levels.

```
$(".box").children().hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("border-color", "grey");
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().css("border-color", "");
    $(this).css("border-color", "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give it a different class.  You have the option of using JavaScript to detect which element is being hovered, but I wouldn't suggest this.

You could try

```
.container > .box > .box:hover
```

Comment: I think my question was unclear. I've edited the original post to make it easier to understand what I need.

Answer (score -1):

### Updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/2hDB9/11/

Basically, there's not an easy way.  You kind of have to fake it, so to speak.  See the code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
        Line 1.
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        Line 2.
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height:50px;
    padding:50px;
}

.container:hover {
}

.box2 {
    height:50px;
    width:75%;
    border:2px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: -110px;
}

.box2:hover {
    border:2px solid red;
}

.box1{
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
    top: -50px;
    left: -50px;
    border:2px solid black;

}

.box1:hover{
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

This makes box2 "appear" to be a child of box1 by using relative positioning, when in reality, box1 is not the parent of box2, they are siblings.

Comment: I think my question was unclear. I've edited the original post to make it easier to understand what I need.